# Embedding Ubunato in PowerPoint Problem

Tags: fonts

I made a PowerPoint Presentation and want to embed the fonts so the presentation appears the same when shared. I got a message that Ubuntu (3 different weights) could not be embedded. In Powerpoint help is says:
**Why a certain font can't be embedded (2 reasons):**

It's an unsupported font, such as Adobe Postscript Type 1 or Apple Advanced Typography (ATT)

Permission to embed the font wasn't granted by the creator. Even though the font is supported TrueType or OpenType

The font is a TTF and I read some of the licensing material and there doesn't seem to be an embedding restriction. I was wondering if there is anything I can do to get the font to embed?